# html calling perl subroutine and return values from subroutine to display in the html

Tags: perl

here is my html code

```
<html>
<title>Results</title>
<body><h1> Here are your results</h1>

<p>Please click the Button to see your result run by Ravi's team.</p>
<form action='index.pl' method='post'>
<input type='submit' value='submit'>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

and index.pl is my perl and my subroutine is as follows.

```
sub my_result{

    my $run;
    my $dir="/kbio/sraja/BenzoExposedDataSet/database/Output";
    my $parsebphtml = "/parse_bphtml.pl";
    my $olgacsvfile = "/database/Output/sample.csv";
    my @bp=<$dir/*.bp>;

    $run ="perl $parsebphtml > $olgacsvfile";
       # print "$com\n";
    system($run)==0 or  my_err("Could not run $run\n");
    #printing the table
    open(F,"$olgacsvfile") or my_err("Could not open the csv ($olgacsvfile) file");
       print "<h2> Average Results </h2>";
       print  "<table border=1>";
       while(my $line=<F>){
          print "<tr>";
          my @cells= split ',',$line;
          foreach my $cell (@cells)
          {
                print "<td colspan=1>$cell</td>";
          }
          print "</tr>";

       }
       print "</table>";

}
```

So as you see, table is what i need to return to results.html 
Any help would be really appreciable.

thanks . 
Geet

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how much work you want to do but, if you want to keep it simple give a try at the `HTML::Template` module. Here is a simple usage example.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset=utf-8>
        <title>A random page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <TMPL_VAR NAME=page_content> 
    </body>
</html>
```

My perl code contained something like this. Better yet, check the documentation at [http://metacpan.org/pod/HTML::Template](http://metacpan.org/pod/HTML%3a%3aTemplate) .

```
use HTML::Template;

sub my_result {
   return $html_string;
}

my $master_template = HTML::Template->new(filename => "Path to html template file");
$master_template->param('page_content' => my_result());
```

Depending on how far you plan on going with this, I would recommend that you a more advanced templating system such as the one used by the mojolicious framework (http://mojolicio.us/perldoc/Mojo/Template).

Cheers,
MrMcKizzle